# A genetic disease that makes humans of any origin have epicanthic folds (slanted eyes)

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, genetics, diseases

I imagined for a future film, a 21 years old human of French nationality and citizenship named Thérèse Arielle Huguette Flavie Alexandre (Alexandre can be both a given name and a surname, in this case, Alexandre is a surname). They (Thérèse Alexandre is a closeted non-binary AFAB person) has the following features:

1. Thérèse Alexandre has epicanthic folds.
2. They has a deep nasally voice (they sounds like Jessica Darrow with a nasal tumour), they is 1.40 metre tall and they weighs 32 kilograms.
3. Finally, Alexandre is somewhat multiracial: their paternal grandfather was a White Frenchman, their paternal grandmother was a Basque, their maternal grandfather was an Ashkenazi Jew, and their maternal grandmother was an Italian woman.

So, I wonder if there is a real life genetic disease that makes humans of any origin have epicanthic folds, and being a skinny little person with a deep voice.

Note: I wrote Alexandre's ethnicity because if almost humans of Mongoloid ancestry have epicanthic folds, and this feature is occasionally present in humans of Congoloid ancestry, and humans of Australoid ancestry, in humans of Caucasoid ancestry, having epicanthic folds is exceptional (especially if we are talking about West Eurasians) (West Eurasians include both Europeans, and North Africans and South-Western Asians).

Comment: (1) T.A.H.F.A. is not multiracial -- they are pure Caucasian aka White. But see point 3 below. (2) Epicanthic folds [do occur](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Epicanthic_fold&oldid=1102509977#Lower-frequency_populations) in pure Europeans. With a considerably lower frequency than in Central and East Asians, but they do. Here is [a picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jens_Byggmark_Schladming_2008.jpg) of Swedish alpine skier Jens Byggmark, for example. (3) Many European populations have old admixtures of Central Asian blood, courtesy of a certain G. Khan and others.

Comment: (a) Your entire first paragraph has nothing at all to do with your question. Is that intentional, or does it affect the question? (b) You list two conditions (#1 and #2), but ask a question with four (adding skinny and little). Are you asking for a known disease that causes (1) epicanthic folds, (2) a deep, nasally voice, (3) below average weight, and (4) below-average height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Epicanthic fold prevalence can sometimes be found as a sign of
> congenital abnormality, such as in Noonan syndrome and Zellweger
> syndrome. Medical conditions that cause the nasal bridge not to
> develop and project are also associated with epicanthic fold. About
> 60% of individuals with Down syndrome (also known as trisomy 21) have
> prominent epicanthic folds.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Epicanthic_fold&oldid=1102509977#Lower-frequency_populations) accessed 2022 Aug 6.

Also, as AlexP mentioned, epicanthic folds can occur in white people.